# ML.net FastForestRegressor output not as expected

Tags: c#, machine-learning, regression, ml.net

With using the standard FastForestRegressor like this:

`pipeline.Add(new FastForestRegressor());`

My expected result is more of an 'average' than a 'this must be it' prediction.

The following image contains time (HH:mm:ss) slots, with a number:
[image]

The higher the number, the more likely my prediction should give me that hour from the number. Now, in bold at the bottom you can see the predictions, which are indeed some kind of average of all the given values. it predicts a time that does not even has an entry. What I expect:

1. Column1: 9:00:00 has 140 values, so it should return a prediction close around this one
2. Column2: 14:00:00 has 152 vales, the other 2 below are also high, so something in that range between 14:00:00-16:00:00.

I tried to tweak the parameters of the FastForestRegressor but that doesn't seem to change anything at all.

My data is stored as:

```
time,day
480,1
480,1
```

..etc.

Now, for the upper left one in the image (8:00:00 110), 110 lines are of values (480,1) are stored in a file. Maybe I should make an extra column with the amount?

To me it seems like I have to adjust some grouping, or smoothing, so it takes the highest possible candidate, and not an average, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Is the stored data what you're feeding the algorithm to train on? I'm not sure I get how that translates to what's in the image.

Comment: In the stored data, fime is the hour in minutes, and day an int for each column. The count is the amount of rows in de file

Comment: how many data did you experiment with? could you share full code and let's see what you trying.